# NullPointerException on a 2D array of objects

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D Array called sectionArray which is of type Student class. Each student has a name and an array[] of 5 grades for exam scores. These names and scores are divided into to sections in a file that must be read. I keep getting a nullPointer on my sectionArray no matter what I change. Thank you for any suggestions.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ProgressReport {

    private Student[][] sectionArray;// each student has a name,
                                     // grade, average,
                                     // and the array of scores
    private File file;
    private Scanner inputFile;

    public ProgressReport() throws IOException {
        sectionArray = new Student[2][];
        file = new File("Lab5A.in.txt");
        inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return the values in the sectionArray
     */
    public Student[][] getSectionArray() {
        return sectionArray;
    }

    /**
     * initialize sectionArray and set the values
     * 
     * @param sectionArray
     *            passed 2D array of Students
     */
    public void setSectionArray(Student[][] sectionArray) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sectionArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sectionArray[i].length; j++) {
                this.sectionArray[i][j] = sectionArray[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * reads from the file and creates new Students
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void readInputFile() throws IOException {
        int colNum = 0;
        int section = 0;
        String name = " ";
        int[] grades = new int[5];

        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            colNum = inputFile.nextInt();// gets size of row
            sectionArray[section] = new Student[colNum];// initialize array

            // iterates through colNum amount of times
            for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
                name = inputFile.next();// gets next name in column
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    // stores scores for that name
                    grades[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
                }
                // creates new Student with name and grades
                sectionArray[section][j] = new Student(name, grades);
                section++;
            }
        }

        // passes the values in sectionArray
        setSectionArray(sectionArray);
    }
}
```

My student class looks like this:

```
public class Student {

    private String name = " "; // Store the name of the student
    private char grade; // Store the letter grade
    private double average; // Store the average score
    private int[] scores; // Store the five exam scores


    public Student() {
        grade = ' ';
        average = 0.0;
    }

    public Student(String name, int[] score) {
        this.name = name;
        scores = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            scores[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            this.scores[i] = score[i];
        }
    }

    // getters

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public char getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return average;
    }

    // think about changing this to return a different format
    public int[] getScores() {
        return scores;
    }

    // setters
    public void setScore(int[] scores) {

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setGrade(char grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public void setAverage(double average) {
        this.average = average;
    }

    /**
     * determine the average of the five test scores for each student
     */
    public void calculateAverage() {
        double total = 0;
        double average = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
            total += scores[i];
        }
        average = total / scores.length;
        setAverage(average);
    }

    /**
     * Determine the student's letter grade based on average of test scores
     */
    public void calculateGrade() {
        double average = 0;
        average = getAverage();
        if (average <= 100 && average >= 90) {
            setGrade('A');
        } else if (average <= 89 && average >= 80) {
            setGrade('B');
        } else if (average <= 79 && average >= 70) {
            setGrade('C');
        } else if (average <= 69 && average >= 60) {
            setGrade('D');
        } else if (average <= 59 && average >= 0) {
            setGrade('F');
        }

    }

    public String toString() {
        return getName() + " " + getAverage() + " " + getGrade();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should we take guesses about which line you get an exception, or you want to go the easier route, and paste the **full stacktrace of the exception**?

Comment: "no matter what I change" ... then the problem is unsolvable.  But with some more specific information maybe we can help.

Answer (score 2):

The array you are trying to write is initialized with `sectionArray = new Student[2][];`. This will create a matrix (2D array) with 2 columns and only one row, and then you try to set your new values on this array. If you already know the size of the matrix you are going to read from the file, then initialize it with the correct values.

Anyway, I did not get why you are trying to use a 2D array for this. If I understood correctly the purpose of your code, you should be using a `List` instead to store the read data, and since it has a dynamically increasing size you wouldn't have to bother with controlling the indexes like you do with the array. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arraylist_class.htm) to learn how to use lists.